# kubuntu equivalient of shared documents

Tags: shared-folders, kde4

Is there equivalent directories to shared documents, shared pictures etc present in Windows NT 5.1 and later in kubuntu. These folders contain data public to all users.

If how can I tell the desktop environment about which directories I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders under /usr/share are used for this purpose.  Though most are application-specific, you'll find directories for things like fonts, man-pages, documentation (for packages), dictionaries, icons, sounds and backgrounds.  The drawback is that while somethings are collected in one directory (like /usr/share/icons and /usr/share/fonts), other things are spread over many...  E.g. you'll find desktop-backgrounds spread between several /usr/share/* -folders, as each WindowManager/DesktopEnviroment install their own in their own directories under /usr/share (e.g. a background-folder somewhere under/usr/share/kde for KDE).

Comment: Another drawback is that custom files are added to these directories so i guess that the answer is no. What about symlinks from /usr/share/kde?